# What do we call the set of elements fixed by an involution of the second kind?

Tags: notation, terminology, involutions

If $A$
is an algebra over a field $F$,
and $\sigma:A\rightarrow A$
is an involution of the second kind,
then it seems natural to talk about the set $S=\{a\in A\mid\sigma(a)=a\}$.
I am not finding any standard notation or terminology for this.
Admittedly I just got my copy of *The Book of Involutions*,
but I'm giving a talk tomorrow and would love to have a concise and known way of referring to that set.

I realize that when $F$
is of the form $K(\sqrt{-d})$
where $d\in K^+$
and $K\subset\mathbb{R}$,
$S$ is often just $K$,
but this is not the case in the examples I'm working with.

So what do we call it? Also is there a common notation for it?

Comment: I believe the standard notation in the book is $\operatorname{Sym}(A,\sigma)$. You can call them symmetric elements, or simply elements fixed by $\sigma$.

Comment: Okay cool but why not post that as an answer, are you unsure of this?

Comment: What is an involution of the second kind?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It is a function $\sigma:A\rightarrow A$ such that $\forall x,y\in A: \sigma(xy)=\sigma(y)\sigma(x)$ and $\sigma(\sigma(x))=x$, but it does not act trivially on the field $F$ that $A$ is over. This latter condition distinguishes it from an involution of the first kind (which is in addition, $F$-linear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this was a comment rather than an answer so...

"I believe the standard notation in the book is $Sym(A,\sigma)$. You can call them symmetric elements, or simply elements fixed by $\sigma$. – @dbluesk"

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is a group acting on a set $X$, one notation you can use for the set of fixed points of the action is $X^G$. And if $f$ is a function acting on a set $X$, one notation you can use for the set of fixed points of $f$ is $\text{Fix}(f)$. So I think either $A^{\sigma}$ or $\text{Fix}(\sigma)$ is fine, depending on whether you want to emphasize $A$ or $\sigma$.

Comment: I realize that but I was interested specifically in the conventions used in the theory of algebras with involution, which were accurately provided by @dbluesk